# Is it possible to execute a SQL script file stored on the database server using a remote command?

Tags: oracle

Say I have a SQL script physically stored on the database server. Is there a SQL command I can send Oracle from an application to tell it to execute that script?

(Yes, I know this sounds ridiculous. I'm considering it as part of a work around of a very nasty problem that "shouldn't happen" but does.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option would generally be to use the `dbms_scheduler` package to [run an external job](https://community.oracle.com/thread/557102).  This would let you invoke a shell script that started SQL*Plus, connected to the database, and ran your .sql script.

It would also be possible to create a Java stored procedure that uses Java's ability to call out to the operating system to run the same shell script.  That tends to be a bit more of a security issue, though, since you're ending up granting the owner of this procedure privileges to run any command on the database server as the `oracle` user.  That would include things like connecting to the database as SYSDBA or corrupting the database (accidentally or intentionally) so it's something that auditors would generally frown upon.